# MVC DataAnnotations validation (Regular Expression) User Input Not Allow HTML Entities

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have textarea multiline, I want to user **not allow enter html tags and html entities** in textarea, I done with html tags not allow but difficulty with user input html entities.

Below code works when user input html tags.

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"[^<>]*", ErrorMessage = "Html tags are not allowed.")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[StringLength(255)]
[Display(Name = "Message")]
public string message { get; set; }
```

I will try with when user enter html entities like `&nbsp;`,`&lt;`,`&gt;` using regular expression `&[^\s]*` but it's not working.

Please help me. How to user not allow enter html entities and html tags in textarea.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample test case? An input and an expected output would be helpful.

Comment: User not allow input as html tags and html entities. DO NOT ALLOW INPUT LIKE THIS VALUE (`&nbsp;`,`&lt;`,`&gt;`) OR HTML TAGS. only expected string with white space or enter key.

Comment: You can use [RegularExpression(@"[^&]*", ErrorMessage = "Some text.")]

Comment: But this way, you would be able to use only one reguler expression. For using multiple regular expressions I will post soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^<>&]*", ErrorMessage = "Html tags are not allowed.")]
```

Just added & in Reg Exp which will prevent from typing `&nbsp;,&lt;,&gt;`

Hope this helps...Thank you.